# Trying to implement a typed collection

Tags: ios, swift, collections

I have some data which I want to wrap up in a collection. The data comes from two different sources using two different techniques so I'm trying to implement two structs which can conform to a common protocol. I would like to return a type which looks something like this:

```
Collection<Media>
```

But `Collection` is not generic. I have two data sources and therefore two classes which need to implement `Collection` but which I need to return through a single method.

My problem is that I want to return a type which can represent either of the two implementation and which the calling code will understand to represent `Media`.

I've tried building a protocol like this:

```
protocol MediaCollection:Collection {
    subscript(i:Int) -> Media { get }
}
```

But I get complication errors because the code in `Collection` references `Self` and Swift doesn't like that. Telling me that `MediaCollection` cannot be used as a generic constraint because it has `Self` or associated type requirements.

I've also found that if I do something like this:

```
class MediaConnection:Collection {
    var startIndex:Int {...}
    var endIndex:Int {...}
    func index(after i:Int) -> Int {...}
    subscript(i:Int) -> Media {...}
}
```

It will compile the `MediaCollection` class, but when I try to use `Collection` as a type in a method signature I get the same problem.

I'm thinking at the moment the only option is to create a `AbstractMediaCollection` class. Then create a `MediaCollection:AbstractMediaCollection` and use `AbstractMediaCollection` in my method signatures. Really UGLY!

I've done lots of reading but I'm really not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: I think you made a typo, `MediaCollection` can **only** be used as a generic constraint. Do you understand why that is?

Comment: No. I'm struggling with this a bit. I'm used to Java generics. Swift generics seem to have a lot of caveats on them. Resulting in lots of strange errors. I also have specified any generics and if I try and do something like `Collection<Media>`, the compiler rejects it.

Comment: Suppose I have: `let collection: Collection = MediaCollection()`, I fill it up and I say `let element = collection[0]`. What type should `element` be?

Comment: Should return an instance of `Media`. Thats the whole goal of what I'm doing. To wrap up a source of data, which is converted to instances of `Media` as needed and returned through subscripting.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, I'm just walking you through the issue of why it's not working.

Comment: It only returns an instance of `Media` of `collection` is a `MediaCollection`. How is the compiler to know that `collection` (whose type is `Collection`) is a `MediaCollection` instance at run time?

Comment: Ideally I want the compiler to know that the returned collection is managing `Media` instances. It's complicated by the face I have two different classes which need to be returned, yet effectively be seen as the same sort of collection of type `Media`. Does that make sense? My problem is trying to figure this out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131315/discussion-between-alexander-and-drekka).